# Override layout file in vendor directory of theme

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, overrides, vendor

I have created a theme in vendor directory. I want to override layout xml files in my theme directory. I have theme-frontend-themename. I have a folder in this directory named Magento_Theme. I want to override default.xml file. My custom theme " theme-frontend-themename" is not overriding layout files of theme folder.

My path /vendor/vendorname/theme-frontend-themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml but default.xml is not overriding
thanks

Comment: Can you please check you custom theme is applied or not ?

Comment: Please check the spelling file or directory

Comment: yeah custom theme is applying.. i have css and JS in my theme which i can see on frontend.. I have module catalog files as well in my theme. It is getting applied

Comment: app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml make sure the path

Comment: I want to override in vendor directory. 
Here is the path
/vendor/vendorname/theme-frontend-themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

Comment: Hi, its working now in the theme table i changed the type